# Prevent click if it is child element

Tags: javascript, boolean

Would it be a bad idea to use a boolean to determine if child element was clicked or not? Is there any better method?

Note: I don't want to use jquery for this.

See code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body{margin:0;}
#container{height:300px;background:red}
#box{width:500px;height:300px;background:blue;margin:auto}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="box"></div>
</div>
<script>
var hbWindow = window,
    hbDocument = document,
    hbBooleanIfIsOutside = new Boolean(),
    hbIdBox = hbDocument.getElementById('box'),
    hbIdContainer = hbDocument.getElementById('container');

hbWindow.onload = function () {

    hbIdContainer.onclick = function () {
        if(hbBooleanIfIsOutside) {
            alert('you\'re outside!');
        } else {
            alert('you\'re inside!');
        }
        hbBooleanIfIsOutside = true;
    }

    hbIdBox.onclick = function () {
        hbBooleanIfIsOutside = false;
    }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Added new version:**

In this version I am using addEventListener instead.

```
var hbWindow = window,
    hbDocument = document,
    hbIdBox = hbDocument.getElementById('box'),
    hbIdContainer = hbDocument.getElementById('container');

hbWindow.onload = function () {

function inOrOut(e){
    if (!e) e = hbWindow.event;
    if((e.target || e.srcElement).id == 'container') {
        alert('you\'re outside!');
    } else {
        alert('you\'re inside!');
    }
}

hbIdContainer.addEventListener('click', inOrOut, false);

}
```

Comment: why are you aliasing `window` and `document`?

Comment: a habit, sure, but why did you start?

Comment: I am caching all variables to speed up things (but I guess it's micro optimization)

Comment: you're replacing things that are already global with new global variables with longer names. Seems like you're hurting readability and allocating more variables than you actually need. This is the opposite of optimization.

Comment: I am caching to reduce DOM-travel. Let's say I will need the hbWindow variable 100 times in my code. Would you say it's a bad idea? (i am not good at this so please enlighten me). Though, I do know for sure that it's a good idea to cache "hbIdBox"...

Comment: yes, you should absolutely store your selected nodes and such that you want to reuse, because the `getElementById` method returns a specific item. But aliasing the `window` and `document` objects isn't any faster. They're both already global objects, so the lookup cost is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to know what invoked the click, check `event.target`. On IE6-8 you would check the `window.event.srcElement` property.

```
if ( document.body.addEventListener ) {
  document.body.addEventListener("click", alertMe, false);
} else if ( document.body.attachEvent ) {
  document.body.attachEvent("onclick", alertMe);
}

function alertMe(event) {
  console.log( event.target || window.event.srcElement.nodeName );
}
```

So while we're attaching the event to the `document.body`, we can determine by the `target` (or in some cases the `srcElement`) which child triggered the click.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/oxuzek/7/edit

Comment: Thanks Jonathan! When to use "element.addEventListener("click", alertMe, false)" and when to use "element.onclick"? :S

Comment: @user1087110 "onclick" was the old-school method if I'm not mistaken, and should be your last resort after `attachEvent`. Using `addEventListener` you can add multiple event handlers.